# MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'thingName' in params

Tags: node.js, reactjs

In my application backend is node.js and the frontend is react.js,
backend developer has given API we have to pass that in the body, in postman I am getting this response
[image]

How to pass raw data in the body using GET API, I have tried to pass data but I am getting an error

```
     state = {
  thingName: "",
  deviseId: " ",
  policyName: " ",
};

 handleChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  });
  console.log(e.target.value);
};


 handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();


  const certparms = JSON.stringify({
    "thingName": this.state.thingName,
    "policyName": this.state.policyName,
    "deviseId": this.state.deviseId
  });

   console.log(certparms)
 

    axios.get('http://10.84.1.140:3000/cer/create/',certparms,{
     headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  })
   .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if (response.ok) {
              alert("success");
            } else {
              alert("fail");
            }

        })

    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };
```

I am getting the following error in node.js logs
[image]

please give any suggestions.